# SUM and Group by field does not retrieve data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

How I can retrieve data from the `SUM(total)` field? The following code does not produce a value in `sum_tot`:

```
$bill_receipts = $this->BanquetBillMaster->find('all', 
                    array('conditions' => array('status' => 2),
                          'fields' => array('id', 'total', 
                                  '(SUM(total)) AS sum_tot','booking_master_id'),
                          'group' => 'booking_master_id',
                          'contain' => false));

foreach($bill_receipts as $aa)
{
    echo $aa['BanquetBillMaster']['sum_tot'];
}
```

Comment: do you have such field at all in you table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to print the array with `debug( $bill_receipts );`, the sum_tot field is probably in `$aa[ 0 ][ 'sum_tot' ]`. Named fields are placed outside the "normal" structure.